# Most secure strategy for mobile database

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, security

I have to develop an app both for iOS and Android. This app uses a small sqlite database with sensitive data, and depending on the user's input, it makes some process with this data. After this process is made, the database is no longer accessed unless the user has to enter a new input (it's not probable that this happens).

Since the database has sensitive data I have to protect it. I know is impossible to get a complete protection but I would like to make life harder for a possible attacker.

And since I don't know too much about security I'm not sure what would be the best alternative taking into account "difficulty / security".

I've thought in two alternatives:

1) Include the database in the apps and encrypt or obfuscate it.

But I guess it wouldn't be very difficult to get the database with a rooted Android.

2) Have the database stored in a server, each time the user enters the input the app downloads the database, the process is made and after that I remove the database from the app.

But the process takes 5-10 minutes and maybe this time is enough to get the database from the app, so I would have to add the same protection as in 1) plus a protection in the server.

Which would be the best option (difficult / security)? There would be any other options?

I've tried several Google searches but I'm confuse with all that information and I would like to try with the huge acknowledge of this community.

UPDATED:

Well, reading your answers I'm inclined to have a backend and not download the database to the app. It's not the preferred solution of the client, but it seem is the best by far so I'll try to convince it.
Anyway, due to the type of process the app has to do I'm not sure if it's possible with a backend.
Since it's a complete different question I would like to ask it in other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942688/remote-sqlite-queries-from-app

NEW UPDATE:

I keep thinking in this and I don't find a good solution because the process is too complex. I've thought in something I would like to know if it's possible or if it has no sense (sorry but I don't know too much about backend development).

SERVER -> my sqlite database & PHP web services

DEVICE -> a txt file with user inputs (20MB)

1. Device: In the device the txt file is compressed (10MB)
2. Device: The app send the txt file to the server via POST web service.
3. Server: This txt file is stored in the server.
4. Server: This txt file is decompressed.
5. Server: This txt file is loaded into a new table InputTable inside my sqlite database.
6. Server: A new table UserFinalDataTable (almost 10000 rows) is created making lots of queries using InputTable and the rest of my database.
7. Server: UserFinalDataTable is converted into JSON and sended back to the device as the response to the web service called in step 2.
8. Device: The app receive this JSON and converts it to something useful for the app.

Is this possible or any (if not all) of the steps is impossible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The most secure and reliable way is to store the database on your server encrypted with a symmetric encryption algorithm. Better yet if you also use an asymmetric encryption algorithm on top of that, if possible with some sort of forward secrecy, in case your server gets hacked. It all depends on what degree of security you want to achieve.

Another way would be to store the database on the device with the server's encryption key, when needed send the database to your server for decryption and return the decrypted output. Although this doesn't make sense in most situations, especially yours.

Answer (score -1):

Neither.  The most secure way is to keep the database on the server and access it only by webservice, with proper account authentication.  If you send any data at all to a client, a sufficiently motivated attacker will get it.  In the case of a whole database file, it would be trivial to root the device and read it.  And if you encrpyt it, SQLite won't be able to read it (not to mention the decryption key would be local so easily reverse engineered).

Comment: And the server cannot be hacked?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I discarded that option because my client doesn't want to have backend development, it only accept a minimun "backend", only to download the database, it doesn't want any user authentication or store any user data.

Comment: Yes @BojanKseneman, of course, but I've always thought that hacking a Android app is easier (by far) than hacking a server. Because of that I'm thinking in that option.

Comment: Hacking anything where the attacker physically controls the hardware is always easier than hacking something where you do.  There's always the option of rooting, or even removing the sd card and using an sd card reader if he's willing to go that far.  It all depends on how paranoid you want to be.

Comment: Do you really control your hardware? Did you built it yourself to be so certain? I wouldn't be so sure about that.

Comment: I never said a server was impossible to hack.  Just a hell of a lot harder, compared to a remote device where the only protection is "the default OS (which is open source and thus moddable) in its default configuration will not allow this directory to be read, unless the user is root".

Answer (score -1):

The most secure strategy you say....backend server with a db and web service.

Answer (score -1):

Use [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) to encrypt your db.

It works either on iOS and Android

Comment: @zaph I don't understand your comment. Can you explain?

Comment: Is thw data encrypted and decrypted on the same device, server or iOS device? If not how do they share the same key in a secure manner?

Comment: db encrypted/decrypted on the device. Not sure about version for server. Key is simple NSString, so it is opted to you how you share it: hardcode in the code, setup/send from server, or generate and send to server in secure way